# How to get only playable songs in US?

Tags: facebook, spotify

I'm working on a spotify app with facebook api.

I have the following query.

**me/music.listens?limit=5&util=1 week ago**

or

**[friend id]/music.listens?limit=5&util=1 week ago**

when i get tracks from the above api, I get songs that're not playable in US. Is there a parameter or a way to get songs that are playable in US only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can retrieve a list of what the user listened to in any of the music apps, but unless you have some other agreement with the providers of the music (e.g. spotify, rdio) there's no way to know if some other user can listen to the same songs.

edit: based on iKenndac's answer, it seems there's a Spotify API to determine playability by region, but you can't get the info from Facebook's API

Comment: @lgv // yes, you're correct. There's no way to find it with facebook api. Since i'm working on Spotify in-app application, I could use spotify Track model (https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/7542b91118.html) then check isPlayable property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Spotify [Web APIs](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/web-api/) to look up territory availability.